# jQuery: сделать ссылку не активной после первого клика (точнее .click событие)

Tags: jquery, ajax

Добрый вечер.
Можно ли отключить прослушивание события .click?

Имеем изображение с 'слушающим' событием в jQuery .click . При нажатии на него в аякс уходят данные и изображение перезагружается.

Если очень быстро нажимать на изображение, картинка не успевает заменится и в ajax уходят данные одной и той же картинки.

Думаю может быть можно как-то после первого нажатия, в ajax beforeSend убрать прослушивание .click, а при приходе нового изображения в ajax success слова включить прослушивание?
Или может быть это можно решить как-то легче?

**UPDATE:**

**RedMonkey**, вот, набросал по вашему примеру - но не заработало. Ajax запросы просто не срабатывают, даже не начинаются. Или я что-то не так написал? Вставил сюда, потому что не помещалось в комментариях.

```
$('#left').click(function(){
$('#left').css('border','1px solid red');  //при первом вешаем картинке КРАСНЫЙ бордер
    var ajaxSend,
      click = function(){
        if(ajaxSend)// проверяем выполняется ли сейчас запрос
            return;// если идёт запрос делаем прерывание функции
    ajaxSend = true;// устанавливаем флаг, что идёт запрос

    $.ajax({
      url:'all ok here',
      type:'all ok here',
      data:'all ok here',
      success:function(){
        $('#left'.)css('border','1px solid black');  //при возврате вешаем картинке черный бордер
        ajaxSend = false;// снимаем флаг
      }
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var ajaxSend,
    click = function(){
        if(ajaxSend)// проверяем выполняется ли сейчас запрос
            return;// если идёт запрос делаем прерывание функции
        ajaxSend = true;// устанавливаем флаг, что идёт запрос
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function(){
                        // делаем что-то
                        ajaxSend = false;// снимаем флаг
                    }
        });
    }
```

Comment: загляните в тему, пожалуйста, там UPDATE

Comment: эти поля должны быть заполнены(адрес куда обращаемся, тип запроса(post или get) и данные которые передаются на сервер)
    
url:'',
type:'',
data:'',

Comment: плюс ко всему ты не возвращаешь статус ajaxSend = false; без этого у тебя другие запросы не пойдут

Comment: нет, нет.. это я когда редактировал - ошибся  
       ajaxSend = false;// снимаем флаг
это у меня стоит  
 
про url,data я тоже знаю) просто тут с нуля писал чтобы код отформатировать, решил не вписывать)  

и оно таки все равно не хочет.

Comment: и ещё один момент, не сразу заметил, функция click не вызывается? в общем запиши так:  
var ajaxSend,  
    click = function(){  
  if(ajaxSend)  
   return;  
  ajaxSend = true;  
  $('#left').css('border','1px solid red');   
  
  $.ajax({  
   url:'index.php',  
   type:'post',  
   data:'id=12&po=0',  
   success:function(){  
     $('#left'.)css('border','1px solid black');  
     ajaxSend = false;  
    }
  });
 }
$('#left').bind('click', click);

Comment: Вот бывает же :)  
Игрался сейчас пол пол часа с этим кодом, так элемент вообще не реагировал. Уже думал писать сюда, как попробовал последний штрих - $('#left').bind('click', click); поставил в самый низ. И заработало. Первый раз просто .bind использую, не работал еще с таким синтаксисом. Спасибо вам огромнейшое! :)

Answer (score 2):

Ну так это можно сделать стандартными средствами.

Добавление события:

```
function addEvent(elem, type, handler){
    if (elem.addEventListener){
        elem.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on"+type, handler);
    };
};
```

Удаление события:

```
function removeEvent(elem, type, handler){
    if (elem.removeEventListener){
        elem.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else {
        elem.detachEvent("on"+type, handler);
    };
};
```

Используешь так: 
Вешаешь обработчики событий на картинку. Делаешь Callback функцию, в которой первым делом удаляешь обработчик с этого события, а потом выполняешь аякс запрос, в котором будет еще один callback устанавливающий событие на этот элемент. Пока картинка не загрузится, обработчик снова не поставится.

```
function deleteClick(elem, options){
    removeEvent(elem, "click", deleteClick);
    // Делаем POST запрос, в зависимости от вашего фреймворка, 
    // функции могут быть другие.
    ajax.post(elem, options, function(){
        // Какой-то ваш код.
        addEvent(elem, "click", deleteClick);
    });
};
```

Comment: и вам спасибо, но мне на данный момент скрипт RedMonkey мне подходит больше :)

Comment: Ну она jquery написал, а я на чистом JS)

Comment: Мы видим..

Answer (score 2):

Уважаемый тёзка! Вы же сами ответили на свой же вопрос. Я даже сначала не стал отвечать, думал, что и так всё ясно. Есть же опции ajax, которые не надо изобретать.

> **beforeSend** - может содержать функцию, которая должна быть вызвана до передачи запроса. Функция Ajax Event.
>
> **complete** - функция, которая исполняется после завершения запроса AJAX. Функция Ajax Event.
>
> **success** - функция, которая будет вызвана в случае успешного завершения запроса
>
> **timeout** - устанавливает локальное время ожидания для запроса. (если надо)
>
> Есть даже такая опция, как **ifModified** - если установить её в true, то запрос будет выполнен со статусом "успешно", лишь в случае, если ответ от сервера отличается от предыдущего ответа.

Этих инструментов с головой хватает для вашей задачи.

Comment: Их то хватает, но я еще не могу так виртуозно флаги расставлять. Теперь уже буду знать.